# Output data into next cell in row

Tags: excel, vba, offset

I have an issue outputting information into individual cells.

My code runs through all of the outputs before moving onto the next cell where it runs through all the outputs again.
[image]

It should output the information into individual cells like this.
[image]

```vb
Sub Totals()

Dim wrksheet As Worksheet
Dim Ttls As Variant
Dim x As Long

For x = 1 To 4
    For Each wrksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If wrksheet.Visible And Not wrksheet.Name = "Log" Then
            With wrksheet
                Ttls = .Range("B2", .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Rows.Count
                Worksheets("Log").Range("G17").Offset(0, x - 1).Value = Application.Transpose(Ttls)
            End With
        End If
    Next wrksheet
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: @SJR Currently it loops through all the values and outputs the last value in each cell, id like it to output one value per cell and move onto the next cell. The last value is 46.

Comment: ttls should just be `.Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Rows.Count`  What's the idea behind the x loop?  you are putting it in arr(1), then arr(2)....

Comment: @Nathan_Sav changing the ttls range just outputs 1 for every row count. And honestly yeah the x loop has no place in the code it can be removed. I was using it to loop through the offset?

Comment: Why are you using `arraysheet`, why not simply use `With wrksheet`?

Comment: @FunThomas Okay, that does make the code shorter, but I'm still having the issue with cell output

Comment: Sure, but I would say it's a good habit to clean up the code *before* posting it on SO. Noone wants to read code and guess what the idea behind is. At least I am much more motivated if I see clean, well indented code.

Comment: At what array are you referring to? If at `Ttls`, it is not an array...

Comment: Yeah I realise now I hadn't actually crated an array, what I was hoping to do is store the output of the loop into the array and then transpose to range. But I'm missing steps in between.

Comment: To create an array (From B2 to last row on B:B), you should delete `.Rows.Count` from the end. Then, when you try dropping the array content, you should resize the pasting cells according to the array dimensions... Do you need returning only the first array element, then two of them and so on? Shouldn't it be better to firstly iterate between the sheets (they are less) and after that in the range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what worked:

```
Sub Totals02()

Dim wrksheet As Worksheet
Dim x As Long
Dim Ary As Variant

ReDim Ary(1 To 2, 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)

For Each wrksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Not wrksheet.Name = "Overpayment No Further Action" And Not wrksheet.Name = "Log" Then

        With wrksheet
                x = x + 1
                Ary(1, x) = .Range("B2", .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Rows.Count
           
            End With

        End If
Next wrksheet
Sheets("Log").Range("G17").Resize(1, x).Value = Ary

End Sub
```